# How to mock mongoose document.subdocument.id() function in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I am a beginner in writing unit test cases. I am trying to write unit test for one of the controllers which calls document.subdocument.id() function to check if the subdocument id is valid or not.

Example Code:

Controller function:

```
const validSubDocument = (documentObj, subDocumentId) => { 
  const document = new DocumentModel(documentObj)
  document.subdocument.id(subDocumentId) ? return true : return false
}
```

Test:

```
test("it should return true", () => { 
expect.assertions(1)
  const mockDocument = { 
                 _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("60a4fa38846526d389527da3"),
                 subdocument: [{ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("60a4fa6ff8ba5b0a929c1142")}]
}

const subDocumentId = "60a4fa6ff8ba5b0a929c1142"
const response = validSubDocument(mockDocument, subDocumentId)
expect(response).toBe(true)
)
```

How do I mock document.subdocument.id(subDocumentId) as I am getting error normally 
**TypeError: document.subdocument.id() is not a function**

Comment: Can you please show us your test code?

Comment: @Christian I have edited the original question with example code. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is `DocumentModel`? Its property `subdocument` obviously doesn't have a function called `id`.

Comment: Thanks again @Christian for your response.

DocumentModel is a mongoose model and the subdocument field is an array of subdocuments ( objects  ) in the main document and mongoose by default has this id method to find subdocument by id ( https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#finding-a-subdocument )

The problem I think that I am having is because my mockDocument does not have this id method. So I need help with mocking the id method of mongoose document.subdocument.id()

Thanks :)